# Pygame, set transparency on an image imported using convert_alpha()

Tags: python, image, pygame, png, transparency

in my pygame game, to import jpeg image, I use `convert()`
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert

then, to play with the image transparency (how much we can see trough the image), I use `set_alpha()`
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha

However, to import my png image, which have a tranparent background, I use `convert_alpha()`
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha

but with this way of importing, I can't play with the general transparency using `set_alpha()`. Any other idea to adjust the transparency (how much we see trough the image) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you read the documentation for **set_alpha** you can read this :
*If the Surface format contains per pixel alphas, then this alpha value will be ignored.*

%In your case, with a png image, it's a per pixel alphas. So, you must manage alpha "per pixel". For example, you can do that (not the best code, but easy to understand. Work with png with no/yes transparency only):

```
def change_alpha(img,alpha=255):
  width,height=img.get_size()
  for x in range(0,width):
    for y in range(0,height):
      r,g,b,old_alpha=img.get_at((x,y))
      if old_alpha>0:
        img.set_at((x,y),(r,g,b,alpha))
```

Be carefull, it's "slow", because you manage each pixel which is not at 0 (transparent from your png).
If your png has multiple level of transparency, you should manage the transparency with a better formula, like this:

```
      r,g,b,old_alpha=img.get_at((x,y))
      img.set_at((x,y),(r,g,b,(alpha*old_alpha)/255))
```

And in this case, never modify the original image, but work on a copy to never lose your original alpha.

I hope it will help

===================== EDIT ===================
Add some optimisation because asking in comment

With some caching methodology:

```
class image_with_alpha(object):
    def __init__(self,name=None):
        self.img=None
        self.alpha={}
        if name:
            self.load_image(name)

    def load_image(self,name):
        self.img=pygame.image.load(name)
        self.alpha[255]=self.img
        #self.pre_compute_alpha()

    def pre_compute_alpha(self):
        for alpha in range(0,10):
            self.alpha[alpha]=change_alpha(self.img,alpha)

    def get_img(self,a=255):
        try:
            return self.alpha[a]
        except:
            self.alpha[a]=change_alpha(self.img,a)
        return self.alpha[a]
```

And use it like this : 
Load image:

```
    image=image_with_alpha("test.png")
```

Blit with 60 for alpha:

```
    screen.blit(image.get_img(60),(0,0))
```

And now, it's fast I hope

Comment: I had black frame with the first formula, but the second one is working well :), however it is very slow, my game drop to 25 fps...

Comment: any idea to make it more optimized ?

Comment: I don't know how your game works, and optimisation of a such code depend on how it's used. how many time alpha change? How large are images? Without low level programming, you can use "cache" for data : You will use more memory, but precompute alpha for image will show great improvement without lot of works.

Comment: In fact I use it to make smooth apparition of object in my game (the object is gradually appearing), so, when an object is currently appearing, the function is called on each frame

Comment: So you can uncomment self.pre_compute_alpha() . There is no easy solution because you use python and pygame and multiple alpha. I see two other alternative : Use mask for blit, or use numpy to work with your data. Maybe, use a pygame alternative also which support transparency level. Go luck with that ;).

Answer (score 4):

The fastest solution is probably to use `numpy` array manipulation, it should be fast enough to avoid the need for caching. What's really slow about calculating the alpha value pixel-wise is iterating in Python, while `numpy` does it all in C.

Start out by referencing the image's alpha channel into a `numpy` array. This will create a lock on the image surface; let's remember that for later. Then take the minimum (pixel-wise) of your original alpha and an array full of ones (that will leave you with an array of only ones and zeros), multiply that (pixel-wise) by your desired alpha and copy the result back to the image's alpha channel (still represented by that array reference). Before you can blit the image to the screen, the array reference to the alpha array must be cleared, releasing the lock on the image surface.

```
def change_alpha(img, alpha=255):
    chan = pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha(img)
    chan2 = numpy.minimum(chan, numpy.ones(chan.shape, dtype=chan.dtype)) * alpha
    numpy.copyto(chan, chan2)
    del chan
```

Comment: My gosh great answer in terms of performance! We had C versions but this kicked their butt. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have the answer for you. Pygame's "convert_alpha()" function does not support per pixel alpha. Based on the docs setting alpha will have no effect. However, you can get around this limitation by doing the following. If you load your image using "convert()", and then setting alpha you can get your image to become transparent. Then all you have to do is use "set_colorkey(background color)" to eliminate the background image. Be carful with colorkey because any color in the image that is set as the colorkey will become transparent. The colorkey does not care about per pixel alpha so you can change the alpha of an image and use colorkey at the same time.

Here is the code...

```
#Loading Image
image = pygame.image.load("test.png").convert()

#Setting Alpha
image.set_alpha(some desired alpha)

#Set colorkey To Eliminate Background Color
image.set_colorkey(some background color)
```

I threw this test picture together for testing the code. The image does have transparency around the edges of it.

[This is what it looks like blitted onto a green background without the added alpha. The white part was transparent until loaded with ".convert()"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx5Fy.png)

[This is the finished look of the image with the whole code applied. The alpha has been stripped and reset, and the colorkey has been set to white because it was the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irwAn.png)

I hope this is what you are looking for and hoped my answer helped here.

NOTE* You may want to make a copy of the image before you change its alpha like this without the risk of the image having a "spillover" affect from previous uses.

Answer (score 0):

use set_colorkey(color) to set a transparent color. for example, if you have an image of an apple, and everything but the apple is the color black, you'd use apple.set_colorkey(black), and everything but the apple would be transparent. also, if your having trouble using a jpg image, I'd suggest changing it to a png and then doing .convert().

Comment: you haven't understood my question. I am already using png file. `convert()` is doing black frame on my png, so I use `convert_alpha` instead. The key problem is that I want to configure the general transparency too (how much we see trough the whole image). Normally, I use `set_alpha()` for this goal. However, when you import an image using `convert_alpha()` like I do, `set_alpha() `doesn't work. I am searching a `set_alpha() ` alternative